# Closing android.provider.Settings Intent called from another application

Tags: android

My application needs, the user must have a wifi connection. So, **I called android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS from my application for switching to Phone Settings screen**. From there user can join an existing wi-fi network or he can create a wi-fi hotspot network.

But the problem is that **even though the application is closed or destroyed, the Settings activity remains in memory. How to close the Settings activity when the user reaches my application by pressing back key** after making necessary actions (i.e. join an existing wi-fi network or he can create a wi-fi hotspot network)?

or is there any better way to do this functionality?

Here is my code (Settings screen is invoked using button click)...

```
public void network(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
}
```

Comment: "the Settings activity remains in memory" -- that is perfectly normal. It is how all apps in Android work. Android app processes remain in memory until Android terminates them. What **specific problems** are being caused by the Settings app being in memory until Android gets rid of it?

Comment: When i closed (using back key press) or destroyed ( using remove from recent applications view) my application, android shows Settings screen; not home screen or applications screen. but exit function programmed on my application's activity menu works fine ( it just simply calls homescreen intent). how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Start new intent with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY) flag.

Recommended read:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html